# MySQL multiple MAX statement causing syntax error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query using multiple MAX statements that works when using a single MAX statement. I'm stuck.  The following works:

```
SELECT 
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_pronamic_google_maps_latitude' THEN meta_value END)lat,
FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (SELECT id from wp_posts where post_name = 'Idaho')
```

but this does not:

```
SELECT 
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_pronamic_google_maps_latitude' THEN meta_value END)lat,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_pronamic_google_maps_longitude' THEN meta_value END)long
FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (SELECT id from wp_posts where post_name = 'Idaho')
```

What's wrong?

Comment: does not work HOW? You get a syntax error? Wrong results? `long` is a reserved word and cannot be used as an alias unless you quote it... ``... AS `long```.

Comment: ...which is precisely why we use lat and lon

Comment: thanks, everyone - I've been looking at this too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the syntax hightlighting suggests long is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html) and so you must escape it to use it as an alias. [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/32187)

```
SELECT 
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_pronamic_google_maps_latitude' THEN meta_value END) AS lat,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_pronamic_google_maps_longitude' THEN meta_value END) AS `long`
FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (SELECT id from wp_posts where post_name = 'Idaho')
```